# Trying to output text of a list array in a random order but i keep getting an error with textView.setText(myList[rando]);

Tags: java, android, arrays

With the following the `myList[rando]` is underlined and it says "The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to List"

```
textView.setText(myList[rando]);
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void OnButtonClickDisplayFact(View view)
    {

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("111");
    myList.add("222");
    myList.add("333");

    int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.randomFactText);
    textView.setText(myList[rando]);


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access elements of an array list, use the get method, that is

```
myList.get(rando)
```

`myList[rando]` only works for arrays

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there anywhere I can get detailed tutorials on this stuff? I figured it was simple but I couldn't find anything searching.

Comment: Good place to start would be the api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using array notation where [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) is required

```
textView.setText(myList.get(rando));
```

Have a read of the [Collections Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)